# Can't access gl_InstanceID in vertex shader

Tags: opengl

When I use gl_InstanceID variable in my vertex shader, nothing gets rendered.

Here's a simple shader I wrote to narrow down the problem:

```
#version 150

in vec2 vert;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vert + 0.2 * gl_InstanceID, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here's my rendering loop:

```
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &one);

glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, 3);
```

If I change gl_InstanceID to a constant, everything works as it should and I get one quad rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** Seems like it was a driver bug. The problem disappeared after updating the driver. I have AMD Mobility Radeon HD5000 series.

Comment: Do you check whether your shader compiles correctly? Maybe it returns an error.

Comment: Yes, shader compiles correctly. Linking is fine too. No errors, no warnings.

Comment: Maybe try using `gl_InstanceID` to change color, instead of position. It'll be easier to debug

Comment: Tried already. No luck.

Comment: What OpenGL version do you use? How do you check compilation status? Do you use glGetError() after every OpenGL call?

Comment: Problem is gone. Thanks for trying to help me.